# admin login not working with Symfony framework

Tags: symfony, authentication, admin

I have a requirement to create a separate login, separate from the main login used for website customers, for backend users in Symfony framework version: 2.6.7

Reading through various available searches, I have done the following:

```
app/config/security.yml-
firewalls:
    control-panel:
        pattern: ^/control-panel
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path:     /control-panel/login
            check_path:     /control-panel/login_check
            default_target_path: /control-panel/ordersearch
        logout:
            path:           /control-panel/logout
            target:         /control-panel/login
        anonymous:    true
    main:
        ...
```

I have the following in my routing file:

```
Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml-

admin_login:
    pattern:  /control-panel/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }
admin_login_check:
    pattern:  /control-panel/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
admin_logout:
    pattern:  /control-panel/logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

I have created the SecurityController as follows:

```
   <?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authChecker = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
        $router = $this->container->get('router');

    if ($authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        echo "inside inside at 22";
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('admin_home'), 307);
    } 

    /*if ($authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('user_home'), 307);
    }*/

    /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
    $session = $request->getSession();

    if (class_exists('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security')) {
        $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;
        echo "authErrorKey:".$authErrorKey;
        echo "lastUsernameKey:".$lastUsernameKey;
    } else {
        // BC for SF < 2.6
        $authErrorKey = SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME;
    }

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
        $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
        $session->remove($authErrorKey);
    } else {
        $error = null;
    }
    echo "<BR/>Error:".$error;

    if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
    }

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);
    echo "<BR/>lastusername:".$lastUsername;

    if ($this->has('security.csrf.token_manager')) {
        $csrfToken = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();
    } else {
        // BC for SF < 2.4
        $csrfToken = $this->has('form.csrf_provider')
            ? $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
            : null;
    }

    return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
    ));
}

public function renderLogin(array $data)
{
    $requestAttributes = $this->container->get('request')->attributes;

    if ('admin_login' === $requestAttributes->get('_route')) {
        echo "<BR/>displaying controlpanel indexpage";
        return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:ControlPanel:index.html.twig', $data);
    } else {
        echo "<BR/>displaying fosbundle login html";
        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
    }
}

/*public function checkAction()
{
    echo "INside SecrutityController::checkAction";
}*/


}
```

and my login form which is separate for the admin users is as follows:

```
<div id="customer-main">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="customer-header-logo">
            <img src="images/logo-popup.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="customer-order-finder">
            <form action="{{ path("admin_login_check") }}" method="post" id="customer-form" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                {% if error %}                    
                    <label for="customer" class="error main-error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData) }}</label>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cs_username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
                </div><!-- end input-holder -->
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="password" id="cs_password" name="_password" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                </div><!-- end input-holder -->
                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/control-panel/ordersearch" />
                <div class="btn-row">
                    <button class="btn btn-find-order" type="submit" value="login">Login</button>
                </div><!-- end btn-row -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem:
Login form is rendered, but when I submit after filling up the credentials it redirects to the FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig and not to the admin areas webpages.
What am I missing here? Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!
Sharad

Comment: - { path: ^/control-panel/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

Comment: Thank you habibun. I have added the following under the access_control section in security.yml: 
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
- { path: ^/control-panel/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/control-panel/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Very sorry habibun for replying late. It is still not working. I added another the user provider (user_db pointing to another Entity class), but I wanted to do this using fosuser bundle. So what i did was I implemented the separate login for backend users using Symfony core security features, but trying to do it with FOS bundle didn't work